# Nesting values in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a series of loops that and I need to get the values to pass correctly. Basically I have a product object from hikashop in joomla. In order to get my display to work the way I want it to behave, I had to separate the images into a separate array and use `array_unique` to filter duplicate images as hikashop assigns the default to each product variant and was getting duplicate images for each variant on the display. I need the display to show each filtered image, but then assign the `$char_id` to them image so that when it is clicked on it will change the main product image.

So wher I'm at is that The images are displaying correctly, but it is only picking up the first key in `$characteristic->variant_characteristic_id` for every image rather than getting the unique key for each image.

I fear I'm a bit over my head here, Thanks

Here is my code block:

```
if ($this->element->variants):
    $i = 0;
    foreach($this->element->variants as $variant):
        foreach($variant->characteristics as $k => $characteristic):
            $char_id = $characteristic->variant_characteristic_id;
            $cat_id = $k;
            $char_name = $characteristic->characteristic_value;
            foreach($variant->images as $key => $image):
                $images[$i] = array($key => $image);
                $i++;
            endforeach;
            $images = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $images)));
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($images).'</pre>';
    foreach($images as $image):
        echo '
            <div class="product-thmb-group">
                <img id="hikashop_child_image_'.$char_id.'" class="hikashop_child_image" src="' . $this->image->uploadFolder_url . $image[0]->file_path . '" alt="hikashop_child_image_' . $char_id . '"  />
                <span class="product-thmb-title">'.$char_name.'</span>
            </div>';
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $images)));`

Comment: Good god man, https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md

Comment: @Scott im not sure what im supposed to do with that

Comment: Make your code more readable?

Comment: @Halcyon this is what takes the images array and filters the duplicates

Comment: Bit vague but I guess rather than creating array for just images you should create an array that contains images,char_id,char_name etc & than use that created array in your last foreach.

Comment: @Rikesh that is what my thought was, but im not sure how to execute it as im pretty green with my php

Comment: @Rikesh ok i tried this, but now i am back to my original problem in that i am getting duplicate images as the values are now unique by adding the char_id

Comment: Add your tried code after our unique images logic.

Comment: even after the unique logic, its still only getting the first char_id

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you also provided an example payload, payload being whatever is in
$this->element->variants.

Anyway spotting the problem was easy, you are overwriting the values of
`$char_id, $cat_id, $char_name` on each iteration of the loop.

You are also iterating through all of the images once for each item in `$variant->characteristics` which is probably not what you are intending.
Without seeing the payload that you are trying to parse I can only guess but I think
what you want to do is something along the line of:

```
$i = 0;
$images = [];
foreach($this->element->variants as $variant) {
    $characteristic = $variant->characteristics[$i];
    $image = $variant->images[$i];

    $images[$image] = [
        "id" => $characteristic->variant_characteristic_id,
        "name" => $characteristic->characteristic_value,
        "image" => $image, // this is optional
    ];
    $i++;
}
```

Then you should be able to loop through the array

```
foreach($images as $image => $meta) {
    echo "Image src: ", $image,
         " Id: ", $meta['id'], " Name: ", $meta['name'], "\n";
}
```

Or if you kept the optional assignment above

```
foreach($images as $data) {
    echo "Image src: ", $data['image'],
         " Id: ", $data['id'], " Name: ", $data['name'], "\n";
}
```

Comment: the paylod is pretty large so i printed on the page http://zink.development.webdesign-toledo.com/zink/zink/duck-calls/atm-green-machine

Comment: You are right it is a lot, far to much to weed through. As long as each variant equals exactly one characteristic and one image then my example should work.

Comment: when i put your code in, im am getting an unexpected [ error on the line $images = []; something im doing wrong?

Comment: nah, you are probably using an older version of PHP. Try replacing [] with array(). and "$images[$image] = [" should become "$images[$image] = array(" followed by a ");" instead of "];"

Comment: i ammended the output of the payload to make it simpler to read, go to http://zink.development.webdesign-toledo.com/zink/zink/apparel-accesories/shirts/product/493-long-sleeve-black-shirt

Comment: I noticed that the indexes of the array that is characteristics does not correspond to the indexes of images. So the question is, how do you know which characteristic matches which image? Is it always the first characteristic for the first image or what exactly is it that you are trying to acomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your help, after looking at this, I advised the client we need to do something different as there is now way to accomplish what we need to do with out a major rewrite of the cart component.